# O365 Calendar API recurring meeting info not returned

Tags: ms-office, preview

I am using the O365 API for Calendar, which I understand is currently in preview. When querying the /Calendar/Events endpoints, all created events are returned, but does not seem to be returning the correct "Recurrence" info. I made several events in O365 that recur every workday with no end date, but the API does not seem to return this info.

Is there a workaround for this to get meeting recurring info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photohunts,
To see the recurrence information, you will need to navigate to the specific Event. 
For example:

```
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Events('AAMkADU5OWRjMWIwLThmNTMtNGM0NC1iM2UwLWEzODE3NjZlOTAwYQBGAAAAAABhjWDlvPXlRIwLplz9WovhBwAGqPuO3lPFTZQQq7HNVCBIAAAB3pf9AABBCWIB9tA-TaTLczumGiYyAACHmWVwAAA=')
```

you will see information like this below:

```
Recurrence: {
Pattern: {
Type: "Weekly",
Interval: 1,
Month: 0,
Index: "First",
FirstDayOfWeek: "Sunday",
DayOfMonth: 0,
DaysOfWeek: [
"Thursday"
]
},
Range: {
Type: "EndDate",
StartDate: "2014-07-03T00:00:00-07:00",
EndDate: "2014-12-31T00:00:00-08:00",
NumberOfOccurrences: 0
}
}
```

Comment: Is there not a way to identify if an event recurs without navigating into the individual event? From a practical standpoint, I would like to know if an event recurs before looking at its pattern and range. As with most user's calendars, they can have many many events and looping through each just seems inefficient.

Comment: Photohunts,
The events for a given time period can be queried using the below query.The Type will be 'Occurence'
The $filter on 'Type' occurence is not working due to a bug. But you can query all events for a time period using the below query: 
../EWS/OData/Me/Events?$top=100&$filter=End%20ge%202014-06-06T22:30:00Z%20and%20Start%20le%202020-12-14T22:30:00Z

All times are in UTC